# query to get all not fully paid invoices

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have these tables `invoices`,`payments`,`payments_details`, the `invoices` table have all the invoices that the user should pay created when a contract is created, this contract may have 1 invoice ore more, the payments table have all the payments for a contract (user may pay more one payment for each invoice) and the last table `payments_details` have the details for each payment in the `payments` table E.G. the payment may have deffirent payment methods such as cash, or cash and visa, or chash and visa and cheques. I'm getting payment value by getting the sum for payment method values from payments_details`, here is my tables script :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[invoices](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[con_id] [int] NOT NULL,
[value] [decimal](10, 2) NOT NULL,
[due_date] [date] NULL,
[date] [date] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_due_payments] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[payments]    Script Date: 30/04/2021 09:45:14 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[payments](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [inv_id] [int] NULL,
    [note] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [date] [date] NULL,
    [app_user] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_invoices] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[payments_details]    Script Date: 30/04/2021 09:45:14 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[payments_details](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [pay_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [value] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
    [method] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [date] [date] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Payment_yearly_details] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

here is the table diagram for the database:
[image]

### **I want to get all the invoices from `invoices` that didn't fully pay in `payments`.**

here what I have done as testing:

```
select inv.ID,inv.con_id,inv.due_date 
from invoices inv
cross apply(
select inv_id from payments pay) payy
cross apply(
select coalesce(sum(pd.value), 0) as paid
from payments_details pd group by pd.pay_id) pdd
where inv.ID = payy.inv_id and inv.value != pdd.paid  group by inv.ID, inv.con_id,inv.due_date
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe something like the following should get you what you need.  I assume [value] in the [invoices] table was the total amount of the invoice.

```
SELECT      [inv].[ID]
          , [inv].[con_id]
          , [inv].[due_date]
FROM        [invoices] [inv]
OUTER APPLY (
                SELECT     SUM([pd].[value]) AS [TotalPayments]
                FROM       [payments] [pay]
                INNER JOIN [payments_details] [pd]
                    ON [pd].[pay_id] = [pay].[ID]
                WHERE      [pay].[inv_id] = [inv].[ID]
            ) AS [paymnts]
WHERE       [inv].[value] <> COALESCE([paymnts].[TotalPayments], 0);
```

OUTER APPLY will get you the [SUM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) of all payment_details for the invoice.  We use OUTER APPLY to account for those invoices with no payments and then use [COALESCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in the where clause.

Without sample data I couldn't test it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT inv.ID, inv.con_id, inv.due_date 
FROM invoices inv
LEFT OUTER JOIN payments pay ON pay.inv_id = inv.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN payments_details pd ON pd.pay_id = pay.ID
GROUP BY inv.ID, inv.con_id, inv.due_date, inv.value
HAVING SUM(ISNULL(pd.value, 0)) < inv.value
```